# ERROR 999999 in ModelBuilder because of Undefined Spatial Reference?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.3, error-999999, extract-by-mask

I have a folder with around 300 Shapefiles I want to use as masks in the tool Extract by Mask on the same Raster image. I'm using the following model :

[image]

But I get the following error :

> ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
>
> The table name is invalid.
>
> Failed to  execute (Extract by Mask)

[image]

I'm pretty sure it's because the new raster image loses the original image's spatial reference :

[image]

The original image is in GCS WGS 1984.

**How can I solve this error?**

Comment: Add Define Projection tool to your model  like http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/42854

Comment: To learn why I have chosen this duplicate see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/149981/error-when-creating-data-with-special-characters-and-numbers.  It is the shapefile named `0.shp` that I think is the problem.  Call it `test.shp` instead as a test and see if you start to make progress.  Please always include error messages as text because if they are only in pictures then people with the same problem later will not find them in their searches.

Comment: @Mapperz : I tried adding the Define Projection tool, but it didn't work.

Comment: @PolyGeo : Thanks for the tip! I'll try doing that!

Comment: @PolyGeo : Ok, it worked when I used "Test"! Thanks!